# Separate Keys for Google APIs

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am new to using googles API so please excuse me in advance if the question seems stupid.

If my Android Application makes use of Google Places API and Google Maps API do I need to get a separate API Key for both APIs or can we use one key for both APIs?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one API Key for both,just you have to enable both API service in library tab in google console.